# Help me understand 言わんこっちゃない

Tags: spoken-language, contractions

I don't understand this whatsoever:

> やれやれ
>
> だから**言わんこっちゃない**

especially the bolded part. What real words does that come from?

Context is that the main character got a cold from staying outside all night; his friend then tells him this.

Comment: http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%93%E3%81%93%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 「言{い}わん**こっちゃ**ない」

is the common colloquial form of:

> 「言わない**ことでは**ない」

which is a set phrase meaning:

> "**I told you so**.", "**Didn't I tell you?**", "**That's why I told you**.", etc.

「やれやれ」 just means "Oh dear!" or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for explaining where こっちゃ comes from - this was the bit I didn't understand.